# Tracing cases of failure got

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to populate an integer variable from a character variable. If there is any error found I want to show the error message and trace all the possible cases for failure got.

```
//Defining variable

Define variable char_value as character no-undo initial "kk".

Define variable int_value as integer no-undo.

define variable ix as integer no-undo.

Assign int_value = integer(char_value) no-error.

IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR OR ERROR-STATUS:NUM-MESSAGES > 0 THEN 
DO:
      
MESSAGE ERROR-STATUS:NUM-MESSAGES 
" errors occurred during conversion." SKIP 
"Do you want to view them?" 
VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX QUESTION BUTTONS YES-NO 

UPDATE view-errs AS LOGICAL.

IF view-errs THEN
      DO ix = 1 TO ERROR-STATUS:NUM-MESSAGES:

        MESSAGE ERROR- 
        STATUS:GET-NUMBER(ix) 
        ERROR-STATUS:GET- 
        MESSAGE(ix).
      END.
END.
```

There are two conditions which I want to know.

1. What char value I gave so that no. Of error returns will be more than 1.
2. How can I trace all the possible cases for failure got.

Comment: Your code results in: "Invalid character in numeric input k. (76)".  That is all the information that Progress has to offer about why the conversion of that string failed. There is nothing more to say about it after that. Additional characters (good or bad) in the char_value are not evaluated.

Comment: It doesn’t work that way.  As soon as one invalid character is found the conversion stops. No additional errors will be detected or reported.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in conversion routine does not do what you want it to do.  So you will need to parse your input prior to attempting to convert it.  Something like this:

```
function isDigit returns logical ( input d as character ):
  if length( d ) = 1 then
    return ( index( "0123456789", d ) > 0 ).
   else
    return no.
end.


procedure checkInteger:

  define input  parameter integerString as character no-undo.
  define output parameter errorList     as character no-undo.
  define output parameter ok            as logical   no-undo.

  define variable i as integer   no-undo.
  define variable n as integer   no-undo.
  define variable c as character no-undo.

  ok = yes.

  n = length( integerString ).
  do i = 1 to n:
    c = substring( integerString, i, 1 ).
    if i = 1 and c = "-" then next.
    if isDigit( c ) = no then
      do:
        ok = no.
        errorList = errorList + substitute( "The character '&1' at offset &2 is not a valid integer value~n", c, i ).
      end.
  end.

  errorList = trim( errorList, "~n" ).      // remove the trailing newline (if any)

  return.

end.

define variable ok as logical no-undo.
define variable errorList as character no-undo.

run checkInteger( "12x34y56z789", output errorList, output ok ).

if ok = yes then
  message "string is a properly formed integer, go ahead and convert it".
 else
  message
    "string was not correctly formed, do not try to convert it" skip
    errorList
   view-as alert-box information
 .
```

Note #1  If the input contains unprintable characters the errorList string will display it literally and it will look kind of funny.  You could, of course, encode them to be more readable.  Doing so is left as an exercise.  Or another question.

Note #2  This code makes no attempt to check that the string value will fit into an integer or an int64.  That is also left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

While you can make your parsing as complex as you like, I would just keep it simple and ensure the user is provided enough information, which in this case is the complete input value:

```
def var cc as char initial "kk".
def var ii as int.

ii = integer( cc ).

catch e as progress.lang.error:
  message quoter( cc, "'" ) e:getMessage(1) view-as alert-box.
end catch.
```